# Problems commenting or accepting answers

Tags: support

Is anyone having the same issue I am with not being able to comment on folks' answers to my questions.  I cannot accept answers either.  Also, there is no CSS rendering for the interface for me, making it very difficult to find my way around.  Also, I'm unable to find a relevant tag which puts this post way off topic.

Please help

Comment: What web browser are you using? I'd recommend trying in a different browser if you're facing a lot of CSS issues. You might also be facing JavaScript issues, which would explain the commenting problem.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might have a browser or proxy problem.

Can you try

- clearing your browser cache, and retrying
- doing a "clean install" of another browser (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari)

and see what happens?